# Is it possible to have multiple virtual machines in a vmware so that i can form a local network?

Tags: vmware

I'm trying to setup a distributed system for my development test and learning. I have a vmware workstation and would like to install multiple machines(at least 2) and form a network, so that I can install HDP, Cassandra and do some testing. I know it could be a memory overhead but just want to see the possibility?

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  VMware has a built-in virtual networking hub.  VMs can be configured with virtual network adapters that are connected to slots in this hub, just like a physical hub.  There is even a virtual adapter for the Host machine.  VMs and Host can communicate with each other over this hub, just like a real network.

[VMware Workstation 5.5Configuring a Virtual Network](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net.html)

[Using the Virtual Network Editor in VMware Workstation (KB 1018697)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697)

[Understanding the Virtual Network Editor in VMware Workstation](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2011/06/30/virtual-network-editor-vmware-workstation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do it if you have some networking background. You have to do some configuration but the ability to create a cluster of nodes in any kind of hypervisor, such as Virtual Box or VmWare is definitely possible.